# How to sort and limit pushed data in $group in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

maybe somebody knows..
Each document in my mongoDB collection looks like:

```
[
  _id: 1,
  login: user1,
  strength: {
    a: 5,
    b: 2
  },
  group: 2
]
```

How to find first 10 documents in each group with the greatest sum of strength.a and strength.b?

Example:
I have documents like this:

```
[ login: login1, group: 2, strength: { a: 2, b: 5 } ]

[ login: login2, group: 1, strength: { a: 1, b: 2 } ]

[ login: login3, group: 3, strength: { a: 1, b: 4 } ]

[ login: login5, group: 1, strength: { a: 1, b: 1 } ]

[ login: login6, group: 1, strength: { a: 10, b: 4 } ]

[ login: login7, group: 3, strength: { a: 0, b: 2 } ]

[ login: login8, group: 3, strength: { a: 11, b: 4 } ]
```

I want to get result:

```
[ group: 1, users: [ { login: login6, sumOfStrength: 14 }, { login: login2, sumOfStrength: 3 } ] ]

[ group: 2, users: [ { login: login1, sumOfStrength: 7 } ] ]

[ group: 3, users: [ { login: login8, sumOfStrength: 15 }, { login: login3, sumOfStrength: 5 } ] ]
```

In conclusion, In this example I want to get results grouped by the "group" field, and select only the first two documents with the greatest total of "a" and "b" fields from each group. Is this feasible?

Until now I did it:

```
db.collection('myCollection').aggregate( 
[ 
  { $group: { _id: '$group', users: { $push: { login: '$login', sumOfStrength: { $sum: [ '$strength.a', '$strength.b'] } } } } } 
] )
```

But how sort and limit number of elements in the array "users" for each group?

Comment: What did you do so far?

Comment: Look now, please. I added more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here some directions :

1. `sum` `a`and `b`fields first(Grouping with 
   `_id`field) into a new field for each documents (you can do this in aggregation or you can add a new field in your document structure. I would add a new field so you can create an index with this field)
2. `sort`documents with `group`and new created `a+b` fields
3. make your `group`operation and `push`(push will be already sorted)
4. Use [slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) to get only first 2 elements of `users` array

Answer (score 0):

It's almost done, I have:

```
db.collection('xxx').aggregate( [ 

    { $project: { _id: 1, group: 1, sumOfStrength: { $sum: [ '$strength.a', '$strength.b'] } } },   
    { $sort: { group: 1, sumOfStrength: -1 } },
    { $group: { _id: '$group', users: { $push: { login: '$login', sumOfStrength: '$sumOfStrength' } } } }
]);
```

Where I have to put $slice? Somewhere in $group operation or in another $project? I have no idea..

Comment: You can do it in another `$project`. Documentation link has example

Comment: I got it!. Thanks a lot